# Screen scrolls to the top (Jetpack Compose Pagination)

Tags: android, kotlin, pagination, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to do pagination in my application. First, I'm fetching 20 item from Api (limit) and every time i scroll down to the bottom of the screen, it increase this number by 20 (`nextPage()`). However, when this function is called, the screen goes to the top, but I want it to continue where it left off. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

**CharacterListScreen:**

```
@Composable
fun CharacterListScreen(
    characterListViewModel: CharacterListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val state = characterListViewModel.state.value
    val limit = characterListViewModel.limit.value

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()

        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), state = listState) {
            itemsIndexed(state.characters) { index, character ->
                characterListViewModel.onChangeRecipeScrollPosition(index)
                if ((index + 1) >= limit) {
                    characterListViewModel.nextPage()
                }
                CharacterListItem(character = character)
            }
        }

        if (state.error.isNotBlank()) {
            Text(
                text = state.error,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }
        if (state.isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
        }
    }
}
```

**CharacterListViewModel:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class CharacterListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val characterRepository: CharacterRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val state = mutableStateOf(CharacterListState())
    val limit = mutableStateOf(20)
    var recipeListScrollPosition = 0

    init {
        getCharacters(limit.value, Constants.HEADER)
    }

    private fun getCharacters(limit : Int, header : String) {
        characterRepository.getCharacters(limit, header).onEach { result ->
            when(result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    state.value = CharacterListState(characters = result.data ?: emptyList())
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    state.value = CharacterListState(error = result.message ?: "Unexpected Error")
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    state.value = CharacterListState(isLoading = true)
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    private fun incrementLimit() {
        limit.value = limit.value + 20
    }

    fun onChangeRecipeScrollPosition(position: Int){
        recipeListScrollPosition = position
    }

    fun nextPage() {
            if((recipeListScrollPosition + 1) >= limit.value) {
                incrementLimit()
                characterRepository.getCharacters(limit.value, Constants.HEADER).onEach {result ->
                    when(result) {
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            state.value = CharacterListState(characters = result.data ?: emptyList())
                        }
                        is Resource.Error -> {
                            state.value = CharacterListState(error = result.message ?: "Unexpected Error")
                        }
                        is Resource.Loading -> {
                            state.value = CharacterListState(isLoading = true)
                        }
                    }
                }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
            }
    }

}
```

**CharacterListState:**

```
data class CharacterListState(
    val isLoading : Boolean = false,
    var characters : List<Character> = emptyList(),
    val error : String = ""
)
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what are you trying to achieve with this part: `characterListViewModel.onChangeRecipeScrollPosition(index)
                if ((index + 1) >= limit) {
                    characterListViewModel.nextPage()
                }`

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using `Paging3` library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you are creating `CharacterListState(isLoading = true)` while loading. This creates an object with empty list of elements. So compose renders an empty `LazyColumn` here which resets the scroll state. The easy solution for that could be `state.value = state.value.copy(isLoading = true)`. Then, while loading, the item list can be preserved (and so is the scroll state)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using the LazyListState correctly. In your viewmodel, create an instance of LazyListState:

```
val lazyListState: LazyListState = LazyListState()
```

Pass that into your composable and use it as follows:

```
@Composable
fun CharacterListScreen(
    characterListViewModel: CharacterListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val limit = characterListViewModel.limit.value

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), state = characterListViewModel.lazyListState) {
            itemsIndexed(state.characters) { index, character ->

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't work.

Comment: I misunderstool your question. I updated my solution. This is how I keep the state of the list and it maintains the last scroll postion when adding additional items. Alternatively, you can also use rememberLazyListState. Another thing - You don't need to keep track of limits to determine when to load more data. That's built into the Paging api. You set a paging size and more data will automatically load when the user scrolls to the bottom.